# lxml filter HTML tags that don't have text between children tags

Tags: python, lxml

I have some documents like this

```
....
  <tag1>
     <tag2>Foo</tag2>
     <tag3>Bar</tag3>
  </tag1>

  <tag1>
     <tag2>Foo</tag2>
     <tag3>Bar</tag3>
     Foo
  </tag1>

  <tag1>
     <tag2>Foo</tag2>     
     Foo
     <tag3>Bar</tag3>
  </tag1>

  <tag1>
     Foo
  </tag1>
 ....
```

I want to filter the tags that only have children tags, i.e. don't have some texts between the children tags. In case above, it should return the first `<tag1>`.

My code initially was

```
from lxml import html

html_content = html.fromstring(content)
tag1 = html_content.xpath('//tag1')
tags = []
for tag in tag1:
   exists = False
   for child in tag.getchildren():
      exists = exists or (len(child.tag) == 0)
   if (not exists):
      tags.append(tag)
```

But it turns out `getchildren()` doesn't return the text that is not between any tag. How to do this?

Comment: When you say "only have children tags", do you mean they still must have children tags? So, would `<tag1></tag1>` be included?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`.tail` attribute](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elements-contain-text) of the tags:

```
for tag in tag1:
    exists = False
    for child in tag.getchildren():
        exists = exists or not child.tail.strip()
    if not exists:
        tags.append(tag)
```

Depending on what you mean by "only have children tags", this is equivalent to:

```
for tag in tag1:
  children = tag.getchildren()
  no_extra_text = not any(child.tail.strip() for child in children)
  if children and no_extra_text:
    tags.append(tag)
```

---

Here's an update to include checking for leading text and removing an error when the text is `None` (I figured it would always be a string):

```
for tag in tag1:
  children = tag.getchildren()
  no_extra_text = not any(child.tail and child.tail.strip() for child in children)
  no_text = tag.text and not tag.text.strip()
  if children and no_extra_text and no_text:
    tags.append(tag)
```

Comment: yes, this is pretty much what i meant. thanks a lot!

Comment: wait, does this handles case `<tag1>foo<tag2>bar</tag2></tag1>`?

Comment: @PetraBarus - Updated to handle that case :)

Answer (score 3):

**What method [getchildren()](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#getchildren) does**

> Returns all direct children. The elements are returned in document order.

So getchildren() return nodes. Each node have properties:

- [tag](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#tag),
- [tail](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#tail),
- [text](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#text) and
- others, read [documentation](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html).

For what you asked, the answer is [tail](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#tail) which will give you

> Text after this element's end tag, but before the next sibling element's start tag. This is either a string or the value None, if there was no text.